Achieving partial build for broken Go codebase
I have a generator which generates me code in Go, for example:

foo.go
bar.go
...

After generation, I need to test if my generator is doing good job. For every generated file, I have a test counterpart:

foo_test.go
bar_test.go
...

Now, the problem is that there are hundreds of these tests, and given nature of the project, some of them will be sometimes broken — i.e. potentially "foo.go" might even fail to compile due to syntax error or something like that.
What I want to do is:

Attempt to compile everything
For files which fail to compile, capture compiler problems in a separate file and ignore them onwards for test purposes
For the rest of files (which are syntactically correct and compile successfully), along with their tests, I want to run the tests and capture test output

To make things more complicated, ideally I'd love to keep generates files (foo.go) separate from test files (foo_test.go) — both in separate directories and separate Go packages, something like that:

generated/foo.go
generated/bar.go
tests/foo_test.go
tests/bar_test.go

Keeping them in separate dir allows easy cleanups and separation of version control concerns. Keeping them in separate Go package allows testing that all interfaces I need to be generated are indeed public and would guarantee that tests would never touch private fields.
What I've tried so far
Single dir, single package
Algorithm:

Put everything in one directory
Have go.mod + go.sum with necessary dependencies and module declaration in there
Have all files declare same package my_tests
Start with go test -v foo.go foo_test.go bar.go bar_test.go
If any of these fail (for example, "bar.go" has an error), capture compiler messages and retry without offending files: go test -v foo.go foo_test.go bar_test.go → and then eventually go test -v foo.go foo_test.go because bar_test.go won't survive without bar.go.

It kind of works, but the downsides are massive: I have to put everything in one directory (so git management becomes very messy) and I have to put everything in one Go package (which means that errors of test using private field occasionally might slip in).
Two modules
Algorithm:

Two separate modules in separate dirs, each with their own go.mod + go.sum.

First, I attempt to compile generated package and module with go build foo.go bar.go → bar.go is broken → go build foo.go succeeds at building a package

Next, I go to tests package and module. That one has go.mod including replacement directive:
replace my_generated => ../generated

In it, I try to do go test -v foo_test.go — but, alas, this doesn't seem to work, as go test will make sure that full package "my_generated" is rebuilt, and that will ultimately fail, as previously I've only made it succeed with manually specifying list of allowed files.


Disable compilation offending files by deleting/renaming them
Same as previous, but instead of removing files from go build / go test invocation, hard disable go compiler from finding them to deleting or renaming them.
Works, but it's really ugly as it modifies test directory, so I either need to do full copy of it and run it in separate place, or rename .go -> .disabled and then rename it back after test run.
So, the question is: is there any better method/algorithm I can employ here? Maybe some non-obvious switch in go build system?

Source foo.go and tests foo_test.go belong in the same directory. Always. If code in foo.go and bar.go are independent: Put them into separate packages package foo and package bar (i.e. separate directories). Don't use filename arguments on go test or go build (or go fancy and call e.g. the compiler by hand). Use one module as this stuff seems to have the same lifecycle. If foo.go and foo_test.go are both generated and do not compile: just delete them to compile the rest (if placed into one package)

"Maybe some non-obvious switch in go build system?" - build constraints may provide an alternative to deleting files (e.g. if foo.go and foo_test.go have the constraint //go:build !foo then using go test -tags foo would exclude those files).

To ensure only public APIs are tested, write package foo_test instead of package foo in *_test.go. There's an example in the package documentation.

@Brits Thanks for the insight, I think build constraints and using the tags is exactly what is a good solution here! Do you mind posting that as an answer, so I can accept that?


Maybe some non-obvious switch in go build system?

As mentioned in the comments, build constraints may provide an alternative to deleting files.
For example if foo.go and foo_test.go have the constraint //go:build !foo then using go test -tags foo would exclude those files (and you can specify multiple tags go test -tags foo,bar).
Note: This really just answers your specific question seeking another option. I cannot comment on whether this is really a good option (you question focuses on the what, and does not really mention the why).
